# AWS ECS Service not showing under cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, devops, amazon-ecs

I've been trying to teach myself DevOps, and I created a cluster and then a Service under the cluster that should pull a container from ECR and expose it to a load balancer with a Task (I think--the docs use a lot of words that don't provide a whole lot of clarity). But anyway, the service has disappeared from the services list for the cluster. I tried creating the service again with the same name in Management Console (so I don't have to update my GitHub action), and I get an error because the service already exists. How can I get hold of the service in Management Console to try to fix it or delete it or whatever?

Thanks!

Comment: That's either a bug in the AWS UI, or you have somehow switched which AWS region you are looking at in the console or something. Can you verify the AWS region you are looking at is the correct one you are deploying your service to?

Comment: How can I verify that if I can't get hold of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Get hold of what? I said you should verify the AWS region you are looking at. The selected region is in the top right corner of the AWS web console. For example if you are creating a service in US-West-2 Oregon, but are looking in US-East-2 Ohio in the console, then you won't see the services that are running in Oregon.

Comment: If I can't see it in the console, how can I see what region it thinks it's in?

Comment: I just found this image on Bing by searching for "find region in AWS console" https://caweem.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/aws-ec2-setup-.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure what you're telling me? Go through and click each region and see if it's in there? Honestly, I am pretty sure that's not going to work, because I created a new service under a new name, and I wound up deleting and recreating it, which worked fine the first time--but the second time I got the same error, even though the delete success toast was still on screen.

Comment: That is the kind of detail you should have included in your original question.

Comment: At that point, that wasn't the case. It only happened next time I deleted the service. It also doesn't seem to have spurred any new insights. However, my current working theory is the service is immediately removed from the list but takes a while after the delete success toast to spin down and really be deleted. Bc I was subsequently able to create a service under the first name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I eventually was able to figure out what was going on here, and helpfully this can help someone.

There's an option that's hidden by default that causes your service to roll back if something goes wrong during creation. But even though in CloudFormation, it says it's deleted, it's still kind of hanging out.

[image: Rollback on failures hidden option]

For this reason, I've started just clicking "View in CloudFormation" when launching a new service--this lets you watch what's going on and you can find zombie services and delete them from within the stack.

[image: CloudFormation stack view]

Comment: I had this exact problem today. Classic AWS Console experience. Thanks for the tip.